# hyper_filter (tidync R package) seems not to work for grid with two variables

Tags: r, netcdf4

I have a nc file with the following structure and I am trying to filter given a lat/lon range, but with no success.

Unfortunately, I beg your pardon, but I cannot share this nc files, and I could not find a similar nc file openly available on the web.
I am using version 0.2.4, and I fear I am facing this issue (from the tidync manual)
"Files with compound types are not yet supported and should fail gracefully. Groups are not yet supported."

Any help/solution about subsetting a nc based on lat/lon and variable name, with `tidync` or in case with `ncdf4` is welcome.

```
tidync::tidync(file.in) 

Grids (4) <dimension family> : <associated variables>                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [1]   D3,D2,D1,D5,D0 : var4    **ACTIVE GRID** ( 207360000  values per variable)                                                                                                                                                       
 [2]   D3,D2,D1,D0    : var1, var2, var3                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [3]   D3,D2          : lat, lon                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [4]   D4,D0          : Times                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Dimensions 6 (5 active):                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   dim   name        length   min   max start count  dmin  dmax unlim coord_dim                                                                                                                                                              
   <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>   
 1 D0    Time           240     1   240     1   240     1   240 TRUE  FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
 2 D1    bottom_top       1     1     1     1     1     1     1 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
 3 D2    south_north    300     1   300     1   300     1   300 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
 4 D3    west_east      288     1   288     1   288     1   288 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
 5 D5    nbins           10     1    10     1    10     1    10 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Inactive dimensions:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   dim   name       length   min   max unlim coord_dim                                                                                                                                                                                       
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>                                                                                                                                                                                           
 1 D4    DateStrLen     19     1    19 FALSE FALSE
```

when I try to filter across lat/lon I am getting the following error: any clue about what I am doing wrong?

```
tidync::tidync(file.in) %>%                                                                                               
    tidync::activate(., "D3,D2") %>%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    tidync::hyper_filter(lat = between(lat, 26.9, 27.1) ) 

>  Grids (4) <dimension family> : <associated variables>                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [1]   D3,D2,D1,D5,D0 : var4                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [2]   D3,D2,D1,D0    : var1, var2, var3                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 [3]   D3,D2          : lat, lon    **ACTIVE GRID** ( 86400  values per variable)                                                                                                                                                            
 [4]   D4,D0          : Times                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Dimensions 6 (2 active):                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   dim   name        length   min   max start count  dmin  dmax unlim coord_dim                                                                                                                                                              
   <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>                                                                                                                                                                  
 1 D2    south_north    300     1   300     1   300     1   300 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
 2 D3    west_east      288     1   288     1   288     1   288 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 Inactive dimensions:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   dim   name       length   min   max unlim coord_dim                                                                                                                                                                                       
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>                                                                                                                                                                                           
 1 D0    Time          240     1   240 TRUE  FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                           
 2 D1    bottom_top      1     1     1 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                           
 3 D4    DateStrLen     19     1    19 FALSE FALSE                                                                                                                                                                                           
 4 D5    nbins          10     1    10 FALSE FALSE 
 Warning message:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 In hyper_filter.tidync(., lat = between(lat, 26.9, 27.1)) :                                                                                                                                                                                 
   'lat' not found in active grid, ignoring
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware in tidync you can only filter by dimensions of the active grid, but not by variable. So the following would work:

```
nc <- tidync(file.in)

nc %>% 
activate("D3,D2") %>%
hyper_filter(south_north = between(south_north, 20, 30))
```

I think if you need to filter the actual variable, you need to extract it first using `hyper_array()` or `hyper_tibble()` and then filter as usual with dplyr.

I have tried indexing the dimension by the values of the variable you want to filter (on my own nc dataset) but couldn't get it to work. Something along these lines could be a start...

```
nc %>% 
activate("D3,D2") %>%
hyper_filter(south_north = index %in% which("lat" > 26.9 & "lat" < 27.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nc_axes(file.in) to check the variable names. It could be latitude and not lat.